# VBscript でシンボリックリンクのリンク先(実体へのpath)を取得したい。

Tags: vba, vbs

タイトル通りで、VBscript でシンボリックリンクのリンク先(実体へのpath)を取得したいのですがググっても見つけきれませんでした。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、[Shell Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776891.aspx)（いわゆるショートカット）ではなく質問文通り[Symbolic Links](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365680.aspx)に関する質問ですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ここに書かれているとおりです。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624989/how-to-get-target-path-of-a-junction

```
foldername = "C:\the Junction\test"

Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set fsutil = sh.Exec("fsutil reparsepoint query """ & foldername & """")

Do While fsutil.Status = 0
  WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

If fsutil.ExitCode <> 0 Then
  WScript.Echo "An error occurred (" & fsutil.ExitCode & ")."
  WScript.Quit fsutil.ExitCode
End If

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "Substitute Name:\s+(.*)"

For Each m In re.Execute(fsutil.StdOut.ReadAll)
  targetPath = m.SubMatches(0)
Next

WScript.Echo targetPath
```

Comment: 英語が苦手なので日本語のページばかり検索していました。
ありがとうございました。